# Executing a SQL query with an `IN` clause from Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know precious nothing abour Rails, so please excuse my naivete about this question.

I'm trying to modify a piece of code that I got from somewhere to make it execute it for a randomly selected bunch of users. Here it goes:

```
users = RedshiftRecord.connection.execute(<<~SQL
  select distinct user_id
  from tablename
  order by random()
  limit 1000
SQL
).to_a

sql = 'select user_id, count(*) from tablename where user_id in (?) group by user_id'
<Library>.on_replica(:something) do
  Something::SomethingElse.
  connection.
  exec_query(sql, users.join(',')).to_h
end
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...ount(*) from tablename where user_id in (?) group by...
                                                         ^
```

`Users` is an array, I know this coz I executed the following and it resulted in `true`:

```
p users.instance_of? Array
```

Would someone please help me execute this code? I want to execute a simple SQL query that would look like this:

```
select user_id, count(*) from tablename where user_id in (user1,user2,...,user1000) group by user_id
```

Comment: Don't join the array. `exec_query(sql, users).to_h` should be sufficient.

Comment: @dbugger I still get the exact same error after removing the join.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `IN` takes a list of parameters. Using a single bind `IN (?)` and a comma separated string will not magically turn it into a list of arguments. Thats just not how SQL works.

What you want is:

```
where user_id in (?, ?, ?, ...)
```

Where the number of binds matches the length of the array you want to pass.

The simple but hacky way to do this would be just interpolate in *n* number of question marks into the SQL string:

```
binds = Array.new(users.length, '?').join(',')
sql = <<~SQL 
  select user_id, count(*) 
  from tablename 
  where user_id in (#{binds)}) 
  group by user_id'
SQL

<Library>.on_replica(:something) do
  Something::SomethingElse.
    connection.
    exec_query(sql, users).to_h
end
```

But you would typically do this in a Rails app by creating a model and using the ActiveRecord query interface or using Arel to programatically create the SQL query.

Comment: There are other solutions like using `ANY(ARRAY[...])` on Postgres but the are database specific. Its exactly these kind of problems that ORMs where invented to fix.